# Do Named Pipes Clear Read Data

Tags: linux, macos, named-pipes

I am using a named pipe created with `mkfifo` on a Mac to communicate with a Linux VM on the same machine.

Linux is writing, Mac is reading.

**When the read is performed is the data automatically cleared (as fifo implies) or is it left there, causing the file to grow.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data from pipes, named or otherwise, is consumed when read. If you want to write persistent data, use a regular file.

Note that the pipe will grow if data **isn't read**, up to a size limit defined by system configuration.

Comment: is there any way to flush or clear the data from pipe/fifo without read operation